# Timer error when calling asyntask in Android

Tags: java, android, timer, android-asynctask

I have this timer inside a service,  it works perfectly and count... but when i call some asyntask's it gives me error!!

```
Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
    time.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run() {
                // i call my Asyntasks here
       }
    },5000,5000);
```

this gives me error:

```
03-17 02:02:27.167: E/AndroidRuntime(925): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
03-17 02:02:27.167: E/AndroidRuntime(925): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-17 02:02:27.167: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at      Dic.proj.pkg.notifService$1.run(notifService.java:57)
  03-17 02:02:27.167: E/AndroidRuntime(925):    at    java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:289)
  03-17 02:02:27.167: E/AndroidRuntime(925): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
  03-17 02:02:27.167: E/AndroidRuntime(925):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
  03-17 02:02:27.167: E/AndroidRuntime(925):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
  03-17 02:02:27.167: E/AndroidRuntime(925):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
   03-17 02:02:27.167: E/AndroidRuntime(925):   at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:152)
   03-17 02:02:27.167: E/AndroidRuntime(925):   ... 2 more
```

if i put others instructions like Log.d("message");  everythings goes OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AsynchTask** needs to be created/called from a UI thread or at least a thread with a looper to handle callbacks when the task wants to publish anything to the caller thread such as `onPostExcute()` ... and using **Timer** object which runs in its own thread doesn't satisfy this condition.

I suggest you use **Handler** combined with **Timer** to achieve this, or even create your own timer using handler object.

The first idea would look something like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
time.schedule(new TimerTask(){
    public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
            // i call my Asyntasks here
             });
   }
},5000,5000);
```

Take a look here to read more about Handlers and Timers:

[Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

[AsynchTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

and here is  a good tutorial about threads:
[Tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you should be inside UI-thread to start AsyncTasks.

You can try to use [Handler.postDelayed(Runnale, long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) instead of Timer.

Answer (score 1):

The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.

The task instance must be created on the UI thread.

You are creating a new thread. Use a handler. Runs on the main thread

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    //do something
    handler.postDelayed(this, 100000);
}
};
handler.removeCallbacks(task);
handler.post(task);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html